# Sybase proc throws "Incorrect syntax near '='"

Tags: sql, syntax, syntax-error, sybase

I have the following piece of a SELECT query inside a stored procedure i'm developing:

```
AND (
    CASE S.SWITCH
        WHEN 'A' THEN P.TEST = T.OPTION_1
        WHEN 'C' THEN P.TEST = T.OPTION_1 + T.OPTION_2
        WHEN 'G' THEN P.TEST = T.OPTION_3
        WHEN 'N' THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
    END
)
```

I'm getting an `Incorrect syntax near '='` error. Why would it complain about the first equals sign? It's a Sybase server if anyone is interested.

Comment: is this an update query or something? perhaps `then set ...`?

Comment: This thread might help you: http://p2p.wrox.com/sql-server-2000/35645-case-statement-where-clause-logic.html

Comment: A funny thing, the expression you have here works fine in Mysql.  This might be a problem with Sybase's implementation of the case expression.  I am not dissing Sybase or pushing Mysql, all db systems have their quirks.  Just thought this might be a helpful datum.

Comment: @GiliusMaximus Yeah, we wish we could switch to MySQL, but we've avoided the move because of the massive amount of data we'd have to migrate.

Comment: I notice that in sybase the assignment and equal comparison operators are the same ('=').  That being the case, the combination of having this in an and clause and inside a case expression might be causing the parser to see the as an assignment operator.  Have you tried just encasing the expressions in parenthesis like (p.test = t.option_1).  That should not make a difference, but it's the sort of small thing that sometimes trips up parsers.

Comment: @GiliusMaximus Yes, I've tried parentheses: No luck. :(

Comment: Sorry.  Your syntax matches what I am reading from Sybase's documentation, so I am at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You case comparison should be something like below, if you are testing `P.TEST` value based on `S.SWITCH` case.

```
AND (
    P.TEST = 
    CASE 
        WHEN S.SWITCH = 'A' THEN T.OPTION_1
        WHEN S.SWITCH =  'C' THEN T.OPTION_1 + T.OPTION_2
        WHEN S.SWITCH = 'G' THEN T.OPTION_3
        WHEN S.SWITCH = 'N' THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
    END
)
```

If you are comparing based on P.TEST and S.SWITCH, you can do either of following

1. Blorgbeard already provided this answer

   ```
   AND
   (        
       (S.SWITCH = 'A' AND P.TEST = T.OPTION_1) OR
       (S.SWITCH = 'C' AND T.OPTION_1 + T.OPTION_2) OR
       (S.SWITCH = 'G' AND P.TEST = T.OPTION_3) OR
       (S.SWITCH = 'N')
   )
   ```
2. If you want to make case statement work for this, following could be a possible solution.

   ```
   AND (
     CASE 1 = 
       WHEN S.SWITCH = 'A' AND P.TEST = T.OPTION_1 THEN 1
       WHEN S.SWITCH =  'C' AND P.TEST = T.OPTION_1 + T.OPTION_2 THEN 1
       WHEN S.SWITCH = 'G' AND P.TEST = T.OPTION_3 THEN 1
       WHEN S.SWITCH = 'N' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
     END
   )
   ```

Comment: This is comparing `P.TEST` with `TRUE` and `FALSE`, instead of just evaluating to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean expressions don't work like that in SQL. You can reformulate your switch like this:

```
AND (
    (S.SWITCH = 'A' AND P.TEST = T.OPTION_1) OR
    (S.SWITCH = 'C' AND T.OPTION_1 + T.OPTION_2) OR
    (S.SWITCH = 'G' AND P.TEST = T.OPTION_3) OR
    (S.SWITCH = 'N')
)
```

Comment: I'm aware of this solution. I was hoping to use the CASE for clarity. Can you direct me to documentation explaining why CASE won't work in this scenario?

Comment: I don't have a reference, sorry. I suspect it is because the WHERE clause is expecting a *predicate* (expression operator expression), rather than a bare *expression*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Language_elements

Comment: I wish I could believe that, but I've tried sticking `TRUE = ` in front of the `CASE` expression and I'm still getting the error. That should cover what you're describing, yes?

Comment: Interesting.. I'm not sure what the status of the `TRUE` keyword is, and I don't actually have a sybase database to test. Does `WHERE TRUE` work and return all rows? How about `WHERE TRUE = TRUE`?

Comment: Fascinating. I added a simple `SELECT` before. `WHERE TRUE` throws an error: `Incorrect syntax near 'TRUE'`; and `WHERE TRUE = TRUE` throws an error: `Invalid column name 'TRUE'`. However, `WHERE 1 = 1` works. I think I'll try a searched `CASE` version of binary's second suggestion, but that might lose the readability I wanted, so `AND` and `OR` might be the best approach.

Comment: It's a pity the official SQL language specs are not freely available. It seems that boolean expressions are "different" in some way to others, but I don't have a clear definition of the difference. Anyway, in my experience the AND/OR approach is fairly common. It's down to what you find the most readable, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is more of a comment than an answer, but hopefully this will lead to an answer, and I need to do formatted code for this so...

I tried this in Mysql and it worked.  Could you try something like this in Sybase and see what it returns?  The point being, extract the part that failed and test it out and see if you can figure out exactly what is wrong.  It may be that Sybase is pointing to that equal sign but something else is really what is confusing it.

```
set @miller:='C';
set @mtime:=2;
select CASE @miller
    WHEN 'A' THEN @mtime = 1
    WHEN 'C' THEN @mtime = 2
    WHEN 'G' THEN @mtime = 3
    WHEN 'N' THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
    END
```

This returns a 1 since miller = 'C' takes it to check if mtime = 2, which is true, and that means a 1 or true in Mysql.

Could you try and isolate this bit of code like this in Sybase?

Comment: I'm not surprised that works. There are apparently some restrictions and what can be in an `AND` clause.